# Navigation components : Deeplink using uri depending buildType

Tags: android, androidx, deeplink

Any way to read a constant depending buildType `${deepLinkHost}`?

```
debug -> deepLinkUri = http://link.debug/
staging -> deepLinkUri = http://link.staging/
release ->  deepLinkUri=  http://link/
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragment_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_home"
        android:name="..."
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
        <argument
            android:name="token"
            android:defaultValue="@null"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true" />
        <deepLink app:uri="${deepLinkUri}/?code={token}" />
</fragment>
```

This was manage before with manifestPlaceholders.deepLinkHost on build.gradle and deeplinks by activity in the AndroidManifest, but once google uses 1 Activity to N Fragments, how can we manage it with navigation components?

Comment: Do you want to read deepLinkUri or do you want your graph to use different deepLinkUri depending on your build type?

Comment: My graph to use different deepLinkUri depending on my build type. Like if I'm in debug, it should take in consideration uri from debug

Comment: Have you already created build flavors or do you need help with that also?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It looks like it's not currently supported out of the box, but there is a pretty simple workaround.
Normally registering a deep link requires two steps:

1. Add `deepLink` to the navigation graph. Since we can't specify any substitution or a `@string` resource as the uri, let's just define the host name as a variable:
   `<deepLink app:uri="http://{deepLinkHost}/?code={token}" />`. This link will match any host and pass `deepLinkHost` as a parameter.
2. Register an intent-filter in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, so our activity actually reacts on the deep link. The recommended approach for the latest android studio is to add `<nav-graph android:value="@navigation/nav_graph" />` to the manifest, so it generates necessary intent-filter automatically. It will, however, register our activity to accept links with any host, which is probably not what we want. So instead of doing this, let's go with [the standard approach](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html). Basically here we define the intent-filter manually instead of auto-generating it from navigation graph. So we can use manifest substitutions just as we would normally do.

Example

- debug -> http://link.debug/identification?code=123
- staging -> http://link.staging/identification?code=123
- release ->  http://link/identification?code=123

and

- debug -> http://link.debug/banner?id=123
- staging -> http://link.staging/banner?id=123
- release ->  http://link/banner?id=123

build.gradle

```
buildTypes {

        debug {
            manifestPlaceholders.deepLinkUri = "http://link.debug"
        }

        staging {
           manifestPlaceholders.deepLinkUri = "http://link.staging"
        }

        release {
           manifestPlaceholders.deepLinkUri = "http://link"
        }
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity
     android:name=".HomeActivity">
     <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    
         <data
            android:host="${deepLinkUri}"
            android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>   
 </activity>
```

navigation_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragment_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_home"
        android:name="..."
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
        <argument
            android:name="deepLinkUri"
            android:defaultValue="@null"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true" />
        <argument
            android:name="token"
            android:defaultValue="@null"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true" />
        <deepLink app:uri="{deepLinkUri}/identification?code={token}" />
</fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_marketing"
        android:name="..."
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_marketing">
        <argument
            android:name="deepLinkUri"
            android:defaultValue="@null"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true" />
        <argument
            android:name="id"
            app:argType="integer"
            app:nullable="true" />
        <deepLink app:uri="{deepLinkUri}/banner?id={id}" />
</fragment>
```

---

**22.05.2020 Update:**
Starting with the gradle plugin version 3.6 the deep link uri cannot contain parameters in scheme and host parts, it will result in `Improper use of wildcards and/or placeholders in deeplink URI host` error.

Fortunately one can use a wildcard, so to make the approach work again just change the `deepLink` definition in your nav graph file:

`<deepLink app:uri="{deepLinkUri}/banner?id={id}" />` to `<deepLink app:uri=".*/banner?id={id}" />`

Comment: if I use the traditional way, I need to manage all the deeplinks on one activity. Once navigation component just recommend to have one single activity and N fragments @esentsov

Comment: @rguerra the above approach makes navigation components deep linking work with traditional way to register links. So you don't need to handle links in the activity, the library will do it for you and will open the right screen

Comment: yap, thanks. Unfortunately it works just for simple deeplinks. On my case, I'm using firebase dynamic links and I don't know how to manage long links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57868086/navigation-component-seems-just-working-with-short-dynamic-link-firebase

Comment: For guys read this answer: Inject build variables into the manifest https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables

Comment: @esentsov `<deepLink app:uri="${deepLinkUri}` not working for me until I updated to `<deepLink app:uri="{deepLinkUri}` by removing `$`

Comment: Thanks @li2, I fixed it in the answer

Comment: @esentsov I followed your answer and found an issue. I only have one Activity (MainActivity) that hosts multiple fragments. If the MainActivity launch mode is standard, the app will open the deep-linked fragment but there will be multiple app instances opened. If the MainActivity launch mode is singleTask, there will be one app opened but the deep-linked fragment won't be navigated to.

Comment: @HauLuu When you set launch mode to singleTask you also need to override `onNewIntent` in your activity and pass the intent to [NavController.handleDeepLink](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#handleDeepLink(android.content.Intent))

Comment: Oh, yes. I also figure that out. But I use the NavController.navigate(Uri) instead.

Comment: I have `Improper use of wildcards and/or placeholders in deeplink URI host` errors because I forgot to **remove** `<nav-graph android:value="@navigation/nav_graph_main" />` from activity tag in manifest. Remember that folks!

Comment: And in `app:uri` argument in navigation `deepLink` tag you can use any name for your host name, eg. `{anyAwesomePlaceholderName}/identification?code={token}`

Comment: With nav components version 2.2.2 is not possible apparently.

Comment: @LeandroOcampo please see the updates answer, might be it solves the issue

Comment: @esentsov thanks! Working on this feature, I noticed some weird behaviour in the library. It does not have anything to do with this question. In case you are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61951850/android-navigation-components-with-deep-link-onnewintent-called-multiple-times

Comment: @esentsov I have a URIs like `https://staging.example.com/invite/email` for staging and `https://example.com/invite/email` for production. For me `*/invite/email` not working. It thinks it cannot handle the deeplink. FYI, I don't have a nav-graph in the manifest.

Comment: @BhavinDesai check you haven't missed the dot `.*/invite/email`

Comment: @esentsov Saved my day! Actually, in the accepted answer, it is `*.` which should be corrected to `.*`

Comment: @esentsov in my case when I use `.*` wildcard it just open the app and don't open the fragment...looks that the wildcard isn't working for some reason

Comment: just checked and with scheme set as `app` is not working as expected...if I change it to `https` it'll work...what could be the reason?

Comment: @Buntupana if you don't specify the scheme the navigation library sets it to `http[s]` automatically. Try to use something like this `app://.*/deep-link`

Comment: what about `android:autoVerify="true"` with wildcarded host? Is that possible? I don't think so, or I have some issue with my app...

Comment: `android:autoVerify`  works by reading the manifest file of your apk. So as long as you have proper url in the merged manifest (e.g. by e.g. using build-time substitutions as in this answer), you should be fine

Comment: what about only schemes? In my scenario I've different schemes per flavor, I'm trying that approach but seems to not work

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution that supports custom schemes for each flavor

Comment: Wildcards are not supported in the scheme part. So the easiest way would be to add both `<deepLink app:uri="flavor1://host.com/deep-link" />` and `<deepLink app:uri="flavor2://host.com/deep-link" />` to the nav graph and define which one is handled by particular flavor by adding manifest substitution: `<data android:host="host.com" android:scheme="${deepLinkScheme}" />`

Comment: This solution will open your app for any host. Probably not what you want.

Comment: It works for me
`
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="http" />
  <data android:scheme="https" />
  <data android:host="${host}" />
</intent-filter>
`
`
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/example_fragment"
  android:name="com.example.ExampleFragment">
    <deepLink
      android:autoVerify="true"
      app:uri="https://.*/path" />
</fragment>
`

`AGP` version 7.4.1

Comment: Be careful because the 2.05.2020 Update doesn't work as well as defining the whole URL. I have one URL `https://example.com/feature/{param}` and another one `https://example.com/feature/subfeature` and while with exact URLs there are no issues, with the wildcard .* the second URL is mistaken for the first one.

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2022-03-17:**

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36994900#comment35

The fix **will be in AGP 7.3.0-alpha08**.

With this fix, AGP supports manifest placeholders in deep link URI's scheme, host, and path.

Example usage:
`<deepLink app:uri="${scheme}://${host}/${path}" />`

**Old info:**

There is still no valid solution for it.

Please star these two issues for faster resolving (I don't think, that it will help, but maybe...):

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36994900

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110237825

Comment: Still not working properly. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36994900#comment48

Answer (score 1):

**2022-05-27 - SIMPLIFIED ANSWER**

**Solution 1:**

It's possible to accomplish this by:

```
<deepLink app:uri="https://.*example.com/link" />
```

`.*` will support any prefix. If your env is not on prefix, move it to that place.

**UPDATE:**
**IMPORTANT NOTE: This will not work with AppLink**

---

**Solution 2:**

**NOT WORKING AS EXPECTED** - Better solution would be using manifest placeholders:

build.gradle:

```
...
debug {
    manifestPlaceholders = [scheme: "https", host: "dev.example.com"]
}
```

and then:

```
<deepLink app:uri="${scheme}://${host}/link" />
```

It requires gradle `7.3.0-alpha08` or greater. It recognizes the deeplink but it's not properly handling to the right fragment (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36994900#comment48). So stick with solution 1 for now if you wish to use implicit deeplink.

Answer (score 1):

After digging this thread and IssueTrackers, this configuration ended up working and the bonus in my use case was the that the deeplinks do not expose other links in other flavors if you check for Supported Links in the app's App Info in the settings

root build.gradle.kts:
`classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2")`

app build.gradle.kts:

```kotlin
buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("release")
            manifestPlaceholders["host"] = "your_prod_url.com"
        }
    
        getByName("uat") {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("uat")
            manifestPlaceholders["host"] = "your_uat_url.com"
        }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />

                <data android:host="${host}" />

            </intent-filter>
```

Example (login) deeplinked navGraph:

```xml
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:name="com.package.LoginFragment"
        android:label=" "

        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login">

        <deepLink
            android:id="@+id/deepLinkLogin"
            app:uri="${host}/{lang}/login" />

    </fragment>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just simplely adding -

```
<deepLink app:uri=".*/{my_token}" />
```

Worked for me!!! Which also made me surprised that it didn't need any extra code.

**Edit 1:** But the above code also open others URL from others app with my app.It is **GOOD** if you really want it that people open their URL with your app. But if you don't like that then you can try the fix below.
I fixed it with just simply add two deep-link for my two variation of my URL like -

```
<deepLink
    app:uri="http://www.stage.com/{token}" />

<deepLink
    app:uri="http://www.production.com/{token}" />
```